# Add dummy variables to data.frame using for-loop

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I want to add 100 dummies `t1, t2, ..., t100` to a data frame `DF`.

```
DF$'t1' <- ifelse(DF$x==1, 1, 0)
DF$'t2' <- ifelse(DF$x==2, 1, 0)
...
DF$'t100' <- ifelse(DF$x==100, 1, 0)
```

Using for-loop, I tried to code like this:

```
for (i in 1:100) DF$paste("t","i",sep="") <- ifelse(DF$x == i, 1, 0)
```

Can you please correct the R code?

Comment: You should rethink this strategy. Read the introductory material about factors which regression functions will handle appropriately, and stop trying to make R behave like SPSS!

Comment: hint: `model.matrix(~factor(x)-1,data=DF)` (and reset column names appropriately)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (i in 1:100){

    DF[[paste("t",i,sep="")]] <- ifelse(DF$x == i, 1, 0)

}
```

Comment: aagh.  Technically correct, but very very very inefficient and clunky (see @BondedDust comment above).

Comment: Sometimes one should refuse to answer a question on the grounds of charity to the questioner.

Answer (score 1):

Consider below example:

```
#dummy data
x<- matrix(c(1:10,sample(1:15,10)),ncol=2)

#make empty matrix
y <- matrix(rep(0,length(x)*15),ncol=15)

#mark relevant cell
y[x] <- as.logical(x[,1])*1

#pretty output
y <- as.data.frame(y)
colnames(y) <- paste0("t",1:15)
df <- cbind(x=x[,2],y)

df
```